# Chrome unable to find local cookie

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, angular

with angular2-cookie I am creating a cookie and reading the data back which works fine

```
_cookieService.put("test.com", "testCookie");
 console.log(_cookieService.get('test.com'));
```

However when I search for this cookie on chrome it does not show up.

[image: no cookies found for test.com]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not working with angular2-cookie library, so this is more proposal, then answer.

You try ng2-cookies library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-cookies

On my end it works without any problems:

```
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies';

@Injectable()
export class SomeCookieExample {
    constructor(){
        //cookie will expire in 60 seconds
        Cookie.set("cookieName", "cookieValue", 60);
        console.log(Cookie.get("cookieName"));
        Cookie.delete("cookieName");
    }
}
```

Comment: It did work after a while, not sure if it was compile or cache issue.